# Eclipse color setting for whitespace characters

Tags: eclipse

What color setting does Eclipse use for whitespace characters? Examples in the screenshot below are the little » glyphs representing tabs, and the pilcrow ¶ for paragraphs.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@atlanto's answer is outdated now it seems. From Preferences it is still `General -> Editors -> Text Editors` but now there is a "configure visibility" option beside the "Show whitespace characters" checkbox label. There you can configure the transparency (default is 80 out of 255) and which characters appear.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm with a screenshot or something, I work in Studio now.

Comment: @QED Done. Added a hand drawn red circle and everything. :)

Answer (score 20):

Basically, it is Foreground color + Transparency, there are no specific settings for whitespace characters.

- **Transparency** is configurable in

  `Preferences` > `General` > `Editors` > `Text Editors`: click 'configure visibility' link > Transparency level
- **Foreground color** is configurable in

  - For Text Editor:

    `Preferences` > `General` > `Editors` > `Text Editors`: Appearance color options
  - For Java Editor:

    `Preferences` > `Java` > `Editor` > `Syntax Coloring`: Element > Java > Others

Other editors may have their own settings.